# UI Elements placed in the wrong place while running in full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, size

I am having a C# WPF application that runs in full screen. When I place a button in the top right of the canvas and run the application the button doesn't appear. What i figured it out is that the canvas is larger than the screen although I made it the same width and height as the screen resolutions.

PS: The application is working fine on another computer and the canvas size is correct but when I run it on my laptop or PC the same problem appears.

```
<Window x:Name="Mywindow" x:Class="Graduation_Project.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="768" Width="1366" WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowState="Maximized" Topmost="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Canvas Name="workspace">
         <Label x:Name="Print" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="57" Canvas.Top="719" Width="74"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate the size of the Canvas, it should stretch itself to the containing window. Post your XAML.

Comment: I posted it. When i try the same code on different computer the label wont appear in the correct place

Comment: Don't give a size to the window. Let it stretch itself to the available screen space by doing `WindowState=Maximized`. Also that's not the full XAML, I don't see where the Canvas is defined.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `Height="768"` and  `Width="1366"` properties from the Window.

Comment: When i removed the Height and width of the window i couldn't place the button in a certain place in the design as the window size will be different when displaying full screen. 

What i want to is to place a UI Element in the bottom left of the window or canvas and when i run in full screen i find it in the same place.

Comment: `What i want to is to place a UI Element in the bottom left of the window` - That's what a `DockPanel` is for. You shouldn't be using a Canvas and Left and Top Properties to place everything. WPF is not winforms.